# I want to onchange "change" just one time

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, onchange

so: I've been trying to make an onchange change just one time, because i want the object appear on the screen after the first change, and stay on the screen:

```
<select required name="Tamanho" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;font-family: bebas_kairegular;font-size: 26px;" onchange="button();">
    <option value="tamanho" selected disabled id="tamanho">Escolha um tamanho</option>
    <option value="P">P</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
</select>

<div id="button" ><button type="button" onclick="cartClick()" style="font-size: 26px;">Comprar</button></div>
```

and used this javascript function to appear the div on the page

```
  function button() {
  var p = document.getElementById("button");
  if (p.style.display === "none") {
    p.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    p.style.display = "none
  }
 }
button();
```

I don't know what to do to have what i want.
Help me please?

Thank You!

Comment: Please note that SO is not meant as a 'can you please provide this code for me' repository. It is intended as a helpful resource for those that run into problems whilst working out their particular challenge? Perhaps have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

What have tried, what errors occur, where in the code do they occur etc.

Your particular problem would have to include a dedicated variable that determines if there is anything in the cart and display the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correct, you want to show the button after the first item selected and then stay visible. If that is correct, please see below the example using your code. You do not need the `else` section in the code, and I added `display: none` to `#button`.

```js
function button() {
  var p = document.getElementById("button");
  if (p.style.display === "none") {
    p.style.display = "block";
  }
 }
```

```html
<select required name="Tamanho" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;font-family: bebas_kairegular;font-size: 26px;" onchange="button();">
    <option value="tamanho" selected disabled id="tamanho">Escolha um tamanho</option>
    <option value="P">P</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
</select>

<div id="button" style="display:none"><button type="button" onclick="cartClick()" style="font-size: 26px;">Comprar</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to make an `onchange` change just one time

This is what `.removeEventListener()` is for.

Instead of `onchange="button();"` as an inline attribute, you can use `.addEventListener()` in your `<script>`, like this:

```
// GRAB ELEMENT
const selectTamanho = document.querySelector('[name="Tamanho"]');

// ADD THE EVENT LISTENER TO ELEMENT
selectTamanho.addEventListener('change', button);
```

and then, within the `button()` function, you can add the last line:

```
// REMOVE THE EVENT LISTENER FROM ELEMENT
selectTamanho.removeEventListener('change', button);
```

Comment: or pass the  [`once`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) option to the `addEventListener` – `.addEventListener('change', button, {once : true})`

Comment: Excellent point, @pilchard. I do use `false` and `true` when adding `click` event listeners etc., but, although I learned the values of the newer object parameter some time ago, I've found that several years later I never really use them. I'll go and revise them.